# What do I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, heap, recursive-datastructures

Python includes the [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html) module for [min-heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), but I need a [max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). What should I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?

Answer (score 476):

The easiest way is to invert the value of the keys and use heapq.  For example, turn 1000.0 into -1000.0 and 5.0 into -5.0.

Comment: It's also the standard solution.

Comment: uggh; total kludge. I am surprised `heapq` does not provide a reverse.

Comment: Wow. I'm *amazed* that this is not provided by `heapq`, and that there is no good alternative.

Comment: yeah, inverting doesn't help if you don't have `int` / `float`'s... in fact, there really doesn't need to be any sensible inverse for an order in general (take, for instance, something isomorphic to the natural numbers).

Comment: @gatoatigrado: If you have something that doesn't easily map to `int`/`float`, you can invert the ordering by wrapping them in a class with an inverted `__lt__` operator.

Comment: And what if you have a  mix of positive and negative numbers to begin with? Then what?

Comment: @Aerovistae same advice applies: invert the values (i.e. switch the sign) regardless if positive or negative to begin with.

Comment: [nneonneo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12682153/4116239) to a duplicate question provides a complete example of @DanielStutzbach's alternate solution: a wrapper class that reverses the total ordering of the contained class.

Comment: Well, this solution looks painstaking at first. But after implementation, it is actually pretty slick, with minimal code changed.

Comment: Poke. See my answer based on yours.

Comment: Here's an example showing that @DanielStutzbach 's method works https://gist.github.com/jtara1/574e87ffa1b49ac09a892aad1620f2f7

Comment: this is ugly, and how do you invert `string`?

Comment: @boh your best bet is to `import` the private maxheap methods from `heapq` and implement `heappush_max()` yourself using those methods. Or create your own wrapper class around strings such at `heapify()` creates a maxheap for your custom string types.

Comment: heapq STILL hasn't added a maxheap?

Comment: Max-heaps may be available by Python 3.13. See this link for details: https://discuss.python.org/t/make-max-heap-functions-public-in-heapq/16944/9

Answer (score 398):

You can use

```
import heapq
listForTree = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]    
heapq.heapify(listForTree)             # for a min heap
heapq._heapify_max(listForTree)        # for a maxheap!!
```

If you then want to pop elements, use:

```
heapq.heappop(minheap)      # pop from minheap
heapq._heappop_max(maxheap) # pop from maxheap
```

Comment: Looks like there are some undocumented functions for max heap: `_heapify_max`, `_heappushpop_max`, `_siftdown_max`, and `_siftup_max`.

Comment: Wow. I'm *amazed* that there *IS* such a built-in solution in heapq. But then it is totally *unreasonable* that it is *NOT* even slightly mentioned at all in the official document! WTF!

Comment: Somehow I can't find this in Python Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Hi Lijo, looks like _heapify_max  not working for dyanamically added/removed elements? See my code from => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024215/built-in-max-heap-api-in-python, your insights are appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Any of the pop/push functions break the max heap structure, so this method is not feasible.

Comment: DO NOT USE IT. As LinMa and Siddhartha noticed, push/pop breaks the order.

Comment: You can use it as long as you don't push new elements and use `_heappop_max`to pop them

Comment: Just to state the obvious, `_heapify_max` etc. are private functions and therefore not part of the module's API.  Use at your own risk, both with respect to functionality and forwards compatibility.

Comment: @oerpli `._heappop_max` doesn't exist on my Python 2.7.15, only `._heappushpop_max` and `._heapify_max` for the underscore methods. Looks like the interface changed in Python 3 to include it.

Comment: The methods beginning with an underscore are **private** and can be **removed without prior notice**. Do not use them.

Comment: Since they are private and can be removed without prior notice, you can just implement the methods yourself.

Comment: These private methods are built to support `heapq.nsmallest` and `heapq.merge` with `reverse=True`.

Comment: @Siddhartha just use _heapify_max() after each push/pop then!

Comment: @oerpli is there inbuilt method to push element into a max-heap. I tried `heapq._heappush_max(heap, item)` but its not working.

Comment: @Mahesh You can look at the available methods here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/heapq.py

Comment: There is some discussion on possibly making this public API in https://discuss.python.org/t/make-max-heap-functions-public-in-heapq/16944

Comment: **This should no be used**. This is not part of the public API

Comment: Dealing with a negative value is not work for every use case to simulate the maxheap. This approach is better. I don't know why it is private. BTW, It is still working with the new version of python 3.11 for me.
For example, how do you solve this problem with a negative values:
https://leetcode.com/problems/last-stone-weight/description/

Comment: @csmaster if you haven't seen it, here's a solution that use negation to solve that problem: https://github.com/neetcode-gh/leetcode/blob/main/python/1046-last-stone-weight.py

Comment: Based on the link in @wim's comment (https://discuss.python.org/t/make-max-heap-functions-public-in-heapq/16944/8), it seems like max-heaps may be available by Python 3.13.

Answer (score 142):

The solution is to negate your values when you store them in the heap, or invert your object comparison like so:

```
import heapq

class MaxHeapObj(object):
  def __init__(self, val): self.val = val
  def __lt__(self, other): return self.val > other.val
  def __eq__(self, other): return self.val == other.val
  def __str__(self): return str(self.val)
```

Example of a max-heap:

```
maxh = []
heapq.heappush(maxh, MaxHeapObj(x))
x = maxh[0].val  # fetch max value
x = heapq.heappop(maxh).val  # pop max value
```

But you have to remember to wrap and unwrap your values, which requires knowing if you are dealing with a min- or max-heap.

### MinHeap, MaxHeap classes

Adding classes for `MinHeap` and `MaxHeap` objects can simplify your code:

```
class MinHeap(object):
  def __init__(self): self.h = []
  def heappush(self, x): heapq.heappush(self.h, x)
  def heappop(self): return heapq.heappop(self.h)
  def __getitem__(self, i): return self.h[i]
  def __len__(self): return len(self.h)

class MaxHeap(MinHeap):
  def heappush(self, x): heapq.heappush(self.h, MaxHeapObj(x))
  def heappop(self): return heapq.heappop(self.h).val
  def __getitem__(self, i): return self.h[i].val
```

Example usage:

```
minh = MinHeap()
maxh = MaxHeap()
# add some values
minh.heappush(12)
maxh.heappush(12)
minh.heappush(4)
maxh.heappush(4)
# fetch "top" values
print(minh[0], maxh[0])  # "4 12"
# fetch and remove "top" values
print(minh.heappop(), maxh.heappop())  # "4 12"
```

Comment: Nice. I've taken this and added an optional `list` parameter to \_\_init\_\_ in which case I call `heapq.heapify` and also added a `heapreplace` method.

Comment: Surprised that no one caught this typo: MaxHeapInt --> MaxHeapObj.  Otherwise, a very clean solution indeed.

Comment: Interestingly Fanchen Bao's answer to this question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875706/heapq-with-custom-compare-predicate

Comment: Is this line needed? def __eq__(self, other): return self.val == other.val. I think it can also work without it.

Comment: @apadana Yes it is good to have - whether it is needed depends on the `heapify` implementation and what you want to do with your heap. We only need to define `__lt__` and `__eq__` to facilitate all comparisons between `MaxHeapObj` objects (<, <=, ==, >, >=), which may be needed when e.g. searching your heap.

Comment: @ChirazBenAbdelkader Fanchen Bao's  linked answer is using a tuple with a custom key object as first element, rather than using the custom object to wrap the elements, so slightly different. The tuple method allows passing a lambda which is cool.

Answer (score 70):

### **The easiest and ideal solution**

> Multiply the values by -1

There you go. All the highest numbers are now the lowest and vice versa.

Just remember that when you pop an element to multiply it with -1 in order to get the original value again.

Comment: Great, but most solution supports the classes/other types, and won't change actual data. The open question is if multiplying value by -1 won't change them (extremely precise float).

Comment: @AlexBaranowski. That's true, but that has been the response from the maintainer: https://bugs.python.org/issue27295

Comment: Well maintainers have their right not to implement some functionality, but this one IMO is actually useful.

Comment: This could be a good solution for some coding round. Otherwise changing data within an application doesn't sound that great.

Answer (score 21):

The *easiest* way is to convert every element into negative and it will solve your problem.

```
import heapq
heap = []
heapq.heappush(heap, 1*(-1))
heapq.heappush(heap, 10*(-1))
heapq.heappush(heap, 20*(-1))
print(heap)
```

The output will look like:

```
[-20, -1, -10]
```

Comment: What about if you have zero and need to push it into the maxHeap? Sorry, just stuck on that

Answer (score 18):

I also needed to use a max-heap, and I was dealing with integers, so I just wrapped the two methods that I needed from `heap` as follows:

```
import heapq


def heappush(heap, item):
    return heapq.heappush(heap, -item)


def heappop(heap):
    return -heapq.heappop(heap)
```

And then I just replaced my `heapq.heappush()` and `heapq.heappop()` calls with `heappush()` and `heappop()` respectively.

Answer (score 16):

I implemented a max-heap version of heapq and submitted it to PyPI.  (Very slight change of the heapq module's [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) code.)

[heapq_max](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/heapq_max/)

[Heapq_max](https://github.com/he-zhe/heapq_max) (GitHub)

Installation

```
pip install heapq_max
```

Usage

tl;dr: The same as the heapq module, except adding ‘_max’ to all functions.

```
heap_max = []                           # Creates an empty heap
heappush_max(heap_max, item)            # Pushes a new item on the heap
item = heappop_max(heap_max)            # Pops the largest item from the heap
item = heap_max[0]                      # The largest item on the heap without popping it
heapify_max(x)                          # Transforms the list into a heap, in-place, in linear time
item = heapreplace_max(heap_max, item)  # Pops and returns the largest item, and
                                        # adds a new item; the heap size is unchanged
```

Comment: This implementation [uses _private functions of heapq.py](https://github.com/he-zhe/heapq_max/blob/2861f32319ab1981e3531101eea5d20434a99c53/heapq_max/heapq_max.py#L21-L22). Avoid.

Comment: The English on those entries, e.g. on PyPI, could be improved. E.g., all [the articles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s) are missing, and it should probably be *"[max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)"* (not *max Heap* or *maxHeap*).

Answer (score 12):

This is a simple max-heap implementation based on *heapq*. Though it only works with numeric values.

```
import heapq
from typing import List


class MaxHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def top(self):
        return -self.data[0]

    def push(self, val):
        heapq.heappush(self.data, -val)

    def pop(self):
        return -heapq.heappop(self.data)
```

Usage:

```
max_heap = MaxHeap()
max_heap.push(3)
max_heap.push(5)
max_heap.push(1)
print(max_heap.top())  # 5
```

Comment: Nice and simple!

Comment: Easiest to understand code, that needs no explanation.

Comment: This requires that the heap elements support negation, and that's not a given.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way:

```
from heapq import *

h = [5, 7, 9, 1, 3]
h_neg = [-i for i in h]
heapify(h_neg)            # heapify
heappush(h_neg, -2)       # push
print(-heappop(h_neg))    # pop
# 9
```

Comment: How and why is it the best way? What makes it better?

Comment: you are using the wellunderstood stdlib, by inverting your values

Answer (score 4):

If you are inserting keys that are comparable but not int-like, you could potentially override the comparison operators on them (i.e. <= become > and > becomes <=). Otherwise, you can override heapq._siftup in the heapq module (it's all just Python code, in the end).

Comment: “it's all just Python code”: it depends on your Python version and installation. For example, my installed heapq.py has some code after line 309 (`# If available, use C implementation`) that does exactly what the comment describes.

Answer (score 4):

Extending the int class and overriding **__lt__** is one of the ways.

```
import queue
class MyInt(int):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self > other

def main():
    q = queue.PriorityQueue()
    q.put(MyInt(10))
    q.put(MyInt(5))
    q.put(MyInt(1))
    while not q.empty():
        print (q.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's possible, but I feel like it would slow things down a lot and use a lot of extra memory. MyInt can't really be used outside of the heap structure either. But thank you for typing up an example, it's interesting to see.

Comment: Hah! One day after I commented I ran into the situation where I needed to put a custom object into a heap and needed a max heap. I actually re-googled this post and found your answer and based my solution off of it. (Custom object being a Point with x,y coordinate and __lt__ overriding comparing distance from center). Thank you for posting this, I upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

#### Allowing you to chose an arbitrary amount of largest or smallest items

```
import heapq
heap = [23, 7, -4, 18, 23, 42, 37, 2, 8, 2, 23, 7, -4, 18, 23, 42, 37, 2]
heapq.heapify(heap)
print(heapq.nlargest(3, heap))  # [42, 42, 37]
print(heapq.nsmallest(3, heap)) # [-4, -4, 2]
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: My answer is longer than the question. What explanation would you like to add?

Comment: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap and https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html might also be of some help.

Comment: This gives the correct result but doesn't actually use a heap to make it efficient. The doc specifies that nlargest and nsmallest sort the list each time.

Comment: You have just dumped an implementation. E.g, why isn't inversion necessary? Why was this set of functions chosen? Why is the set of chosen functions different from other answers? How is it better / different? How does it answer the question? How is "chose an arbitrary amount of largest or smallest items" related to the question ("What should I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?")? - why is that relevant? For example, does that make it better than other answers? Etc.

Comment: From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*.

Comment: Looks like you spent a lot of time on this questions, you've edited several answers, made lots of comments, I see your name come up 17 times with ctrl-f (as of today). Instead of just griping about my input (and other people too) consider adding to my answer next time. It probably would have taken less time to do that and would have benefited everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a heap wrapper that inverts the values to create a max-heap, as well as a wrapper class for a min-heap to make the library more OOP-like. [Here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/1233be4bb096bdd9cd3223d372d2f3ec) is the gist. There are three classes; Heap (abstract class), HeapMin, and HeapMax.

Methods:

```
isempty() -> bool; obvious
getroot() -> int; returns min/max
push() -> None; equivalent to heapq.heappush
pop() -> int; equivalent to heapq.heappop
view_min()/view_max() -> int; alias for getroot()
pushpop() -> int; equivalent to heapq.pushpop
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on [Apoorv Patne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python/59311063#59311063), here is a fully documented, annotated and tested Python 3 implementation for the general case.

```python
from __future__ import annotations  # To allow "MinHeap.push -> MinHeap:"
from typing import Generic, List, Optional, TypeVar
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush, heapreplace


T = TypeVar('T')


class MinHeap(Generic[T]):
    '''
    MinHeap provides a nicer API around heapq's functionality.
    As it is a minimum heap, the first element of the heap is always the
    smallest.
    >>> h = MinHeap([3, 1, 4, 2])
    >>> h[0]
    1
    >>> h.peek()
    1
    >>> h.push(5)  # N.B.: the array isn't always fully sorted.
    [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
    >>> h.pop()
    1
    >>> h.pop()
    2
    >>> h.pop()
    3
    >>> h.push(3).push(2)
    [2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> h.replace(1)
    2
    >>> h
    [1, 3, 4, 5]
    '''
    def __init__(self, array: Optional[List[T]] = None):
        if array is None:
            array = []
        heapify(array)
        self.h = array
    def push(self, x: T) -> MinHeap:
        heappush(self.h, x)
        return self  # To allow chaining operations.
    def peek(self) -> T:
        return self.h[0]
    def pop(self) -> T:
        return heappop(self.h)
    def replace(self, x: T) -> T:
        return heapreplace(self.h, x)
    def __getitem__(self, i) -> T:
        return self.h[i]
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.h)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.h)
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.h)


class Reverse(Generic[T]):
    '''
    Wrap around the provided object, reversing the comparison operators.
    >>> 1 < 2
    True
    >>> Reverse(1) < Reverse(2)
    False
    >>> Reverse(2) < Reverse(1)
    True
    >>> Reverse(1) <= Reverse(2)
    False
    >>> Reverse(2) <= Reverse(1)
    True
    >>> Reverse(2) <= Reverse(2)
    True
    >>> Reverse(1) == Reverse(1)
    True
    >>> Reverse(2) > Reverse(1)
    False
    >>> Reverse(1) > Reverse(2)
    True
    >>> Reverse(2) >= Reverse(1)
    False
    >>> Reverse(1) >= Reverse(2)
    True
    >>> Reverse(1)
    1
    '''
    def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
        self.x = x
    def __lt__(self, other: Reverse) -> bool:
        return other.x.__lt__(self.x)
    def __le__(self, other: Reverse) -> bool:
        return other.x.__le__(self.x)
    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        return self.x == other.x
    def __ne__(self, other: Reverse) -> bool:
        return other.x.__ne__(self.x)
    def __ge__(self, other: Reverse) -> bool:
        return other.x.__ge__(self.x)
    def __gt__(self, other: Reverse) -> bool:
        return other.x.__gt__(self.x)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.x)


class MaxHeap(MinHeap):
    '''
    MaxHeap provides an implement of a maximum-heap, as heapq does not provide
    it. As it is a maximum heap, the first element of the heap is always the
    largest. It achieves this by wrapping around elements with Reverse,
    which reverses the comparison operations used by heapq.
    >>> h = MaxHeap([3, 1, 4, 2])
    >>> h[0]
    4
    >>> h.peek()
    4
    >>> h.push(5)  # N.B.: the array isn't always fully sorted.
    [5, 4, 3, 1, 2]
    >>> h.pop()
    5
    >>> h.pop()
    4
    >>> h.pop()
    3
    >>> h.pop()
    2
    >>> h.push(3).push(2).push(4)
    [4, 3, 2, 1]
    >>> h.replace(1)
    4
    >>> h
    [3, 1, 2, 1]
    '''
    def __init__(self, array: Optional[List[T]] = None):
        if array is not None:
            array = [Reverse(x) for x in array]  # Wrap with Reverse.
        super().__init__(array)
    def push(self, x: T) -> MaxHeap:
        super().push(Reverse(x))
        return self
    def peek(self) -> T:
        return super().peek().x
    def pop(self) -> T:
        return super().pop().x
    def replace(self, x: T) -> T:
        return super().replace(Reverse(x)).x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

https://gist.github.com/marccarre/577a55850998da02af3d4b7b98152cf4

Answer (score 1):

The *heapq* module has everything you need to implement a max-heap.
It does only the *heappush* functionality of a max-heap.
I've demonstrated below how to overcome that.

Add this function in the heapq module:

```
def _heappush_max(heap, item):
    """Push item onto heap, maintaining the heap invariant."""
    heap.append(item)
    _siftdown_max(heap, 0, len(heap)-1)
```

And at the end, add this:

```
try:
    from _heapq import _heappush_max
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Voila! It's done.

**PS** - to go to *heapq* function. First write "import heapq" in your editor and then right click 'heapq' and select go to definition.

Comment: Re *"right click 'heapq' and select go to definition"*: What editor did you use?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you would like to get the largest K element using max heap, you can do the following trick:

```
nums= [3,2,1,5,6,4]
k = 2  #k being the kth largest element you want to get
heapq.heapify(nums) 
temp = heapq.nlargest(k, nums)
return temp[-1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the time complexity for this is O(MlogM) where M = len(nums), which defeats the purpose of heapq. 
See the implementation and comments for `nlargest` here -> https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7dc72b8d4f2c9d1eed20f314fd6425eab66cbc89/Lib/heapq.py#L521

Comment: Thank you for your informative comment, will make sure to check the attached link.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in heap in Python, but here is how build it by yourself. The algorithm is working, but about the efficiency I don't know.

```
class Heap:

    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = []
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, heap):
        self.heap = heap
        self.size = len(self.heap)

    def heappush(self, value):
        self.heap.append(value)
        self.size += 1

    def heapify(self, heap, index=0):

        mid = int(self.size /2)
        """
            If you want to travel great value from the bottom to the top, you need to repeat swapping by the height of the tree.
            I don't know how I can get the height of the tree. That's why I use sezi/2.
            You can find the height by this formula:
            2^(x) = size+1  Why 2^x? Because the tree is growing exponentially
            xln(2) = ln(size+1)
            x = ln(size+1)/ln(2)
        """

        for i in range(mid):
            self.createTee(heap, index)

        return heap

    def createTee(self, heap, shiftindex):

        """
        """
        """

            This 'pos' variable refer to the index of the parent, only parent with children
                    (1)
                (2)      (3)           Here the size of the list is 7/2 = 3
            (4)   (5)  (6)  (7)        The number of parents is 3, but we use {2, 1, 0} in a 'while' loop.
                                       That is why a set 'pos' to -1.

        """
        pos = int(self.size /2) -1
        """
            This if you want to sort this heap list. We should swap the maximum value in the root of the tree with the last
            value in the list and if you want to repeat this until sort all list, you will need to prevent the function from
            change what we already sorted. I should decrease the size of the list. That will heapify on it.

        """

        newsize = self.size - shiftindex
        while pos >= 0:
            left_child = pos * 2 + 1
            right_child = pos * 2 + 2
            # This means that left child is exist
            if left_child < newsize:
                if right_child < newsize:

                    # If the right child exits, we want to check if the left
                    # child > rightchild.
                    #
                    # If the right child doesn't exist, we can check that
                    # we will get error out of range.
                    if heap[pos] < heap[left_child] and heap[left_child]  > heap[right_child]:
                        heap[left_child], heap[pos] = heap[pos], heap[left_child]
                # Here if the right child doesn't exist
                else:
                    if heap[pos] < heap[left_child]:
                        heap[left_child], heap[pos] = heap[pos], heap[left_child]
            # If the right child exists
            if right_child < newsize:
                if heap[pos] < heap[right_child]:
                    heap[right_child], heap[pos] = heap[pos], heap[right_child]
            pos -= 1

        return heap

    def sort(self):
        k = 1
        for i in range(self.size -1, 0, -1):
            """
            Because this is max-heap, we swap root with last element in the list

            """
            self.heap [0], self.heap[i] = self.heap[i], self.heap[0]
            self.heapify(self.heap, k)
            k += 1

        return self.heap


h = Heap()
h.add([5, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 50, -1])
h.heappush(-2)
print(" before heapify ")
print(h.heap)
print(" after heapify ")
print(h.heapify(h.heap, 0))
print(" after sort ")
print(h.sort())
```

#### Output

##### Before heapify

[5, 7, 0, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 50, -1, -2]

##### After heapify

[50, 30, 20, 8, 9, 10, 0, 7, 5, -1, -2]

##### After sort

[-2, -1, 0, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 50]

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 0, 7, 8, 90, 67, 31, 2, 5, 567]
# max-heap sort will lead the array to ascending order
def maxheap(arr, p):

    for i in range(len(arr)-p):
        if i > 0:
            child = i
            parent = (i + 1)//2 - 1

            while arr[child]> arr[parent] and child != 0:
                arr[child], arr[parent] = arr[parent], arr[child]
                child = parent
                parent = (parent + 1)//2 -1


def heapsort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        maxheap(arr, i)
        arr[0], arr[len(arr)-i-1] = arr[len(arr)-i-1], arr[0]

    return arr


print(heapsort(arr))
```

Try this.

Comment: Who said anything about sorting? Why is that relevant? Why is it necessary? Where was this copied from?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a package called [heap_class](https://pypi.org/project/heap-class/0.9.0b1/) that implements max-heaps, and also wraps the various heap functions into a list-compatible environment.

```
>>> from heap_class import Heap
>>> h = Heap([3, 1, 9, 20], max=True)
>>> h.pop()
20

>>> h.peek()  # The same as h[0]
9

>>> h.push(17)  # Or h.append(17)
>>> h[0]  # The same as h.peek()
17

>>> h[1]  # Inefficient, but it works
9
```

Get a min-heap from a max-heap.

```
>>> y = reversed(h)
>>> y.peek()
1

>>> y  # The representation is inefficient, but correct
Heap([1, 3, 9, 17], max=False)

>>> 9 in y
True

>>> y.raw()  # Underlying heap structure
[1, 3, 17, 9]
```

As others have mentioned, working with strings and complex objects in a max-heap is rather hard in heapq because of the different forms of negation. It is easy with the heap_class implementation:

```
>>> h = Heap(('aa', 4), ('aa', 5), ('zz', 2), ('zz', 1), max=True)
>>> h.pop()
('zz', 2)
```

Custom keys are supported and work with subsequent pushes/appends and pops:

```
>>> vals = [('Adam', 'Smith'), ('Zeta', 'Jones')]
>>> h = Heap(vals, key=lambda name: name[1])
>>> h.peek()  # Jones comes before Smith
('Zeta', 'Jones')

>>> h.push(('Aaron', 'Allen'))
>>> h.peek()
('Aaron', 'Allen')
```

(The implementation is built on heapq functions, so it is all in C or with C-wrappers, except heappush and heapreplace on max-heap which is in Python.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import heapq
customers = []
heapq.heappush(customers, (2, "Harry"))
heapq.heappush(customers, (3, "Charles"))
heapq.heappush(customers, (1, "Riya"))
heapq.heappush(customers, (4, "Stacy"))
while customers:
     print(heapq.heappop(customers)) #for min heap
     # for max heap
     #heapq._heapify_max(customers) 
     #print(heapq._heappop_max(customers))
```

Comment: Try this and please let me know whether it is working or not