# Min heap is, but is a max heap module defined in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, heap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python)

Python has a min heap implemented in the heapq module.  However, if one would want a max heap, would one have to build from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

You could multiply your numbers by -1 and use the min heap.

Answer (score 0):

No need to implement a max heap from scratch. You can easily employ a bit of math to turn your min heap into a max heap!

See [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg238926.html) and [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502295/) - but really [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python).