# How efficient is Python's max function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, big-o

The function `max()` which returns the maximum element from a list . . . what is its running time (in Python 3) in terms of [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's O(n), since it must check every element.  If you want better performance for max, you can use the [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) module.  However, you have to [negate each value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python), since `heapq` provides a min heap. Inserting an element into a heap is O(log n).

Comment: Inserting n elements into a heap is O(n log n).

Comment: @Greg, yes, I meant inserting a single element.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: It is (at least if you implement it by yourself) possible to add `n` elements into a heap in `O(n)` (simply call `siftdown` for all elements in reverse order).

Comment: **maximum element from a list...**  If the list is general (not sorted or otherwise organized, there is no way to get better than O(n) -- unless you have multiprocesor, parallel system.

Comment: I believe @pepr is right. Wouldn't I have to look at every item in the list anyway to add it to the heapq / priority queue, thus O(n)?

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is O(n) unless you are using a different datastructure supporting the max of a value collection due to some implementation invariant.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are using it.
If you want to maximize based on a function "someFunc", it'll take `O(len(l)*k)` where k is the time function "someFunc" takes to run.

```
maxVal = max(l, key=somefunc)
```

But yes for normal case it should just iterate over the list and find the max using normal compare function.