# Finding Max Shape of Multiple .npz files

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number of .npz files that potentially vary in shape and I'd like to find which file has the larges shape. The npzs have 2 arrays within in them, and I'm looking for the largest of the 2nd.  The following snippet works, but it takes longer than I expected to return shapes.  Is this the most efficient way of achieving this?   I'm worried about scaling because it currently takes a couple seconds to find the max shape[1] and I'm only looping through 4 arrays

```
frameMax =0 
for f in npzs:
    d = np.load(f,mmap_mode='r')
    if d['arr_0'].shape[1]>frameMax:
        frameMax = d['arr_0'].shape[1]
    d=None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that I/O operations might be relatively slow. That said, you can reduce the logic for finding the maximum to the following using the builtin [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) which will run in [O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454030/how-efficient-is-pythons-max-function) time, and removes the need for the assignments you did:

```
frameMax = max([np.load(f,mmap_mode='r')['arr_0'].shape[1] for f in npzs])
```

Comment: You're probably correct and it's most likely an I/O bottleneck.  This doesn't really speed anything up, but it definitely looks more sleek.  Thanks, @moses-koledoye