# built-in max heap API in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, queue, priority-queue

Default heapq is min queue implementation and wondering if there is an option for max queue? Thanks.

I tried the solution using _heapify_max for max heap, but how to handle dynamically push/pop element? It seems _heapify_max could only be used during initialization time.

```
import heapq

def heapsort(iterable):
    h = []
    for value in iterable:
        heapq.heappush(h, value)
    return [heapq.heappop(h) for i in range(len(h))]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print heapsort([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0])
```

Edit, tried _heapify_max seems not working for dynamically push/pop elements. I tried both methods output the same, both output is, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

```
def heapsort(iterable):
    h = []
    for value in iterable:
        heapq.heappush(h, value)
    return [heapq.heappop(h) for i in range(len(h))]

def heapsort2(iterable):
    h = []
    heapq._heapify_max(h)
    for value in iterable:
        heapq.heappush(h, value)
    return [heapq.heappop(h) for i in range(len(h))]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print heapsort([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0])
    print heapsort2([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0])
```

Thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python)

Comment: @LukasGraf, I am not sure if calling function _heapify_max is good, since I see prefix "_", which seems to be an internal function?

Comment: @LukasGraf, the first solution does not fit me well since I need to handle both integers and strings. :)

Comment: Yes, the situation here isn't really satisfactory. Still, the *question* as such is pretty much an exact duplicate. You may however find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12682153/1599111) helpful.

Comment: @LukasGraf, thanks for all the help. I posted my code, and it seems _heapify_max based solution could not be used in cases which we dynamically pop/push elements? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LukasGraf, posted code which shows _heapify_max solution could not be used in cases which we dynamically pop/push elements, your advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @theJollySin, vote up for your reply. Do you mean `heappop ` or `pop`? If you could post your code snippet, it will be great to reduce confusions.

Comment: _heapify_max will transform your input into a max heap.  However, heappop and heappush are still min-heap based. You can check the source code of heapq module here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py There is actually a _heappop_max function you can import, which should be used in max heap.  There is no _heappush_max available. But you can easily modify heappush function to write one. Or check my version here: https://github.com/he-zhe/heapq_max/blob/master/heapq_max/heapq_max.py#L47

Comment: def heapsort2(iterable):
    h = []
   # heapq._heapify_max(h)  move this line below the for loop it will work
    for value in iterable:
        heapq.heappush(h, value)
    heapq._heapify_max(h)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the past I have simply used [sortedcontainers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers)'s `SortedList` for this, as:

```
> a = SortedList()
> a.add(3)
> a.add(2)
> a.add(1)
> a.pop()
3
```

It's not a heap, but it's fast and works directly as required.

If you absolutely need it to be a heap, you could make a general negation class to hold your items.

```
class Neg():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return -cmp(self.x, other.x)

def maxheappush(heap, item):
    heapq.heappush(heap, Neg(item))

def maxheappop(heap):
    return heapq.heappop(heap).x
```

But that will be using a little more memory.

Comment: good catch. Wondering if your solution works for string, besides numeric types?

Comment: @LinMa That's what the wrapper's for. If you know your data is numeric you can do a little better by just using `-` as in `def maxheappush(heap, item): heapq.heappush(heap, -item)` and `def maxheappop(heap): return -heapq.heappop(heap)`.

Comment: Thanks U2EF1, how and when __cmp__ is called and leveraged?

Comment: @LinMa All the time? It's a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) for comparisons.

Comment: Thanks U2EF1, sorry I may not make myself understood. I mean does heappush or heappop call __cmp__ underlying -- I ask this since I do not see __cmp__ is called explicitly? If so, more details are appreciated.

Comment: @LinMa Yes, operations like `a < b` on `Neg` instances will call `__cmp__`. You can add some print statements if you want to see it being called.

Comment: How to implement a peek/ get_top function on this max heap?

Comment: @anveshtummala With indexing, ala `a[-1]`.

Comment: sorry for necromancing the old thread, but in response to the last comment above, I think it should be `a[0]` to peek the max item (i.e. item at the root of the heap/tree).

Comment: The `class Neg` approach is broken on Python 3. Sadly implementing just `__cmp__` only is not sufficient anymore :'(

Comment: For python3, implementing `__lt__` is enough.

Answer (score 11):

There is a [_heappop_max](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/heapq.py#L179) function in the latest cpython source that you may find useful:

```
def _heappop_max(heap):
    """Maxheap version of a heappop."""
    lastelt = heap.pop()    # raises appropriate IndexError if heap is empty
    if heap:
        returnitem = heap[0]
        heap[0] = lastelt
        heapq._siftup_max(heap, 0)
        return returnitem
    return lastelt
```

If you change the `heappush` logic using  `heapq._siftdown_max` you should get the desired output:

```
def _heappush_max(heap, item):
    heap.append(item)
    heapq._siftdown_max(heap, 0, len(heap)-1)


def _heappop_max(heap):
    """Maxheap version of a heappop."""
    lastelt = heap.pop()  # raises appropriate IndexError if heap is empty
    if heap:
        returnitem = heap[0]
        heap[0] = lastelt
        heapq._siftup_max(heap, 0)
        return returnitem
    return lastelt


def heapsort2(iterable):
    h = []
    heapq._heapify_max(h)
    for value in iterable:
        _heappush_max(h, value)
    return [_heappop_max(h) for i in range(len(h))]
```

Output:

```
In [14]: heapsort2([1,3,6,2,7,9,0,4,5,8])
Out[14]: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

In [15]: heapsort2([7, 8, 9, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 1, 0])
Out[15]: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

In [16]: heapsort2([19,13,15,17,11,10,14,20,18])
Out[16]: [20, 19, 18, 17, 15, 14, 13, 11, 10]

In [17]: heapsort2(["foo","bar","foobar","baz"])
Out[17]: ['foobar', 'foo', 'baz', 'bar']
```