# keep maximum value of container.

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a long array of values. And I know the index where the maximum value is.

At each step, I pick a value under a certain criterion and modify it according to some rules(it is not important here). 
After each modification, I have to know the maximum value of the array.

The simplest method is to compare the modified value `N` and previously maximum value `O` and if `N > O` then update the maximum value as `N`. However things gets tricky if the index which is modified is where the previously maximum value was stored. In this case, I need to sweep array and and find out what is the maximum value which is `O(L)` where `L` is the length of array.
I want to avoid this worst case complexity.

What is the best way to achieve it? ( algorithm or data structure? )

Comment: Two words : heap sort.

Comment: one link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134129/stack-with-find-min-find-max-more-efficient-than-on

Comment: Two links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python

Comment: There's also a question of where the index to be modified comes from. These indices cannot be stored, as each modification potentially invalidates them. Perhaps you want a simple sorted linked list.

Comment: @n.m. Only insertions and deletions will invalidate the indices. I can't be sure, but it doesn't look like those are required operations (`"... pick a value ... modify it ..."`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I've misunderstood the description. No you cannot use a linked list. I think the simplest way is indeed to use a heap.

Answer (score -2):

Store the "previous" previous maximum (P) and compare N against that value when N and O are the same index. P was replaced by N as the current maximum value, so if N is reduced below the value of P then P should once again be the maximum value.

Comment: you don't handle cases of deletion only insertion.

Comment: @Emil - you're right. N could be modified such that it would not be the second highest value behind "P", resulting in needing to search for the new "P"... didn't think of that.

Comment: @0x90, ignoring the shortcoming that Emil pointed out for a second, 1) the question stated that an index was modified, not inserted or deleted, and 2) if N was deleted where N === 0, wouldn't "P" still be the maximum value of the array? (also, in the case of insertion, N and O won't be the same index, and this problem goes away...)

Comment: @huene wasn't read it carefully I was on train, I am leaving all the comments since they point to related subjects.