# How to use queue.PriorityQueue as maxheap

Tags: python, priority-queue, heap

How to use [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) as maxheap?

The default implementation of `queue.PriorityQueue` is minheap, in the documentation also there is no mention whether this can be used or not for maxheap.

Comment: try read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python)

Comment: @Minji heap push is not there in the mentioned link

Comment: One easy way would be to invert the priority. That is, if your item's priority is 2, change it to -2.

Answer (score 6):

PriorityQueue by default only support minheaps.

One way to implement max_heaps with it, could be,

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

# Max Heap
class MaxHeapElement:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.x > other.x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)


max_heap = PriorityQueue()

max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(10))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(20))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(15))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(12))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(27))

while not max_heap.empty():
    print(max_heap.get())
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, the simplest way to get maxHeap is to insert negative of the element.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

max_heap = PriorityQueue()

max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(-10))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(-20))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(-15))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(-12))
max_heap.put(MaxHeapElement(-27))

while not max_heap.empty():
    print(-1*max_heap.get())
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a list:

```
k = [3, 2, 6, 4, 9]
```

Now, let's say you want to print out the max element first (or any other element with the maximum priority).

Then the logic is to reverse the priority by multiplying it with `-1`, then use the `PriorityQueue` class object which supports the min priority queue for making it a max priority queue.

For example:

```
import queue

k = [3, 2, 6, 4, 9]
q = queue.PriorityQueue()
for idx in range(len(k)):
    # We are putting a tuple to queue - (priority, value)
    q.put((-1 * k[idx], idx))

# To print the max priority element, just call the get()
# get() will return tuple, so you need to extract the 2nd element
print(q.get()[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To adhere to the (priority, value) structure for an element in a priority queue, the wrapper class can be modified as below:

```
class MaxHeapElement:    
   def __init__(self, priority, value):
       self.priority = priority
       self.value = value

   def __lt__(self, other):
       return self.priority > other.priority

   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.priority}, {self.value}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert the value of the keys and use heapq. For example, turn 1000.0 into -1000.0 and 5.0 into -5.0.

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heapify

heap = []
heapify(heap)

heappush(heap, -1 * 1000)
heappush(heap, -1 * 5)
-heappop(heap) # return 1000
-heappop(heap) # return 5
```