# Returning a list from longest string length to shortest string length

Tags: python

What is a good way to add elements to a list that automatically adds elements depending on their string length?

For example.

```
class MyQueueSystem():

    def __init__(self, myfunction):
self.myfucntion = myfunction
        self.data = []



    def add(self, item):
        pass
```

For example,

```
def shorter(a, b):
    return len(a) < len(b)

>>> me = MyQueueSystem(shorter)
>>> me.add('111')
>>> me.add('11')
>>> me.add('11111')
>>> print (me.data)
['11111','111','11']
```

item in the add function is an object.

My question is, how do you access a function as a parameter?

edit : I forgot to add a argument in the **Init**

Comment: Does it have to work with the `shorter` function or would it be acceptable to do `me = MyQueueSystem(len)` instead?

Comment: It could. But i rather find a way to work with another function as an argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do I use for a max-heap implementation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python)

Comment: I would suggest another implementation

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sorted` function within your `add(..)` fucntion to sort the list based on the `len`. Below is sample structure for your class:

```
class MyQueueSystem():
    #                    v It should be passed as an argument to `__init__`
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = self._sort_on_length(data)

    def add(self, item):
        self.data = self._sort_on_length(self.data+[item])

    def _sort_on_length(self, sort_list):
        """
        Function to sort the argument `list` based on the length
        in the descending order
        """
        return sorted(sort_list, key=lambda x: -len(x))
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> my_object = MyQueueSystem(['111', '11', '11111'])
>>> my_object.data
['11111', '111', '11']

>>> my_object.add('1111')
>>> my_object.data
['11111', '1111', '111', '11']
```

Comment: @MMF is probably just trolling - "The Timsort algorithm used in Python does multiple sorts efficiently because it can take advantage of any ordering already present in a dataset." https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts