# How to make a queue list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i do queue?

mylist = [1, 2, 3]

i want to enter **mylist** in this function and i want get new list like this:
[4, 2, 3] further [5, 4, 3] further [6, 5, 4] etc

```
def testfunc(mylist):
    return mylist
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to add incrementing numbers to the front of a list?

Comment: yes, i want this

Comment: What you want to actually do ?, Please add what you have tried and what you need help or what error you are getting

Comment: try using `pop` and `append` together.

Comment: at first processing i want get this: [1, 2, 3];
in the second processing i want get this: [4, 2, 3] from [1, 2, 3];
in the third: [5, 4, 3] from [4, 2, 3] etc

Comment: How do you get from [4,2,3] to [5,4,3]?

Comment: Python has both [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#queue.Queue) and [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will insert the given element at the front of the list, then slice to exclude the last item:

```
def enqueue(l, item):
    l.insert(0, item)
    l.pop()
```

If you always want to enqueue the maximum element +1:

```
def enqueue(l):
    l.insert(0, max(l) + 1)
    l.pop()
```

Usage:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
enqueue(mylist)
print(mylist)
enqueue(mylist)
print(mylist)
enqueue(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 2]
[5, 4, 1]
[6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there might be two interpretations to your question (from the comments).

1. enqueuing a provided item to the front of the list and removing an item at the end
2. putting an item in and popping off the smallest item

There are other data structures that may be better suited to what you're ultimately looking to do. I'll give two examples of alternatives. I'm not sure if either of these alone give you exactly what you want, but I think they're steps towards it.

#### Using [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

One comment seems to mention being able to pass the value. That would work well with a deque:

```py
from collections import deque

q = deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
print(q)  # [1, 2, 3]
q.appendleft(4)
print(q)  # [4, 1, 2]
q.appendleft(5)
print(q)  # [5, 4, 1]
```

You can then use `q.popleft` to get the "first" item.

#### Using [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#module-heapq)

Another comment seems to be about keeping just the max value, which would work well to treat your list as a "priority queue":

```py
import heapq

q = [1, 2, 3]
heapq.heapify(q)
print(q)  # [1, 2, 3]

# push item on the heap, and pop the smallest item
heapq.heappushpop(q, 4)
print(q)  # [2, 4, 3]
heapq.heappushpop(q, 5)
print(q)  # [3, 4, 5]
```

`heapq.heappop(q)` from this heap will yield the smallest item. You should use the `heapq` functions to interact with items on this list. You'll notice the order (visually) might not be what you expect, but that's what the `heapq` functions take care of.

If, instead, you want a max-heap, [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501457/what-do-i-use-for-a-max-heap-implementation-in-python) has tons of opinions on that.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this would work for what it seems you want

```
def testfunc(mylist):
    mylist=[mylist[0]+1]+mylist
    mylist.pop(-1)
    return mylist
```

or if you want to always remove the smallest element from the list, change `mylist.pop(-1)` to  `mylist.remove(min(mylist))`

edit to pass new element

```
def testfunc(mylist,newitem):
         mylist=[newitem]+mylist
         mylist.remove(min(mylist))
         return mylist
```

Comment: Missing syntax, You forgot the closing bracket

Comment: @HridayaAgrawal where? i just copied pasted it and it works

Comment: `[mylist[0]+1]+mylist` This

Comment: @HridayaAgrawal that works fine? whats missing?

Comment: almost, but i want to pass my element to mylist

Comment: at first processing: [1, 2, 3]
in the second processing: [4, 2, 3]
in the third processing[5, 4, 3] etc

Comment: @RAINGM made an update, is that what you want?

Comment: almost, after processing [4, 2, 3] and element i get [5, 4, 2], i need [5, 4, 3]

Comment: @RAINGM yea the latest update should do that. you need to remove the smallest element and not just the last one like i initially did

Comment: wow, yea, that exactly what i need, thx for the support